# Custom UIView class not linked with xib in swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm trying to make a custom UIView class in swift. I added a UIView xib to my project, and a .swift class. When I try to link them together by specifying the custom class of the .xib, it doesn't seem to link the two together because the assistant editor still shows the NSObject.h file if I set it to automatic, and I can't add any IBOutlets to the .swift class.

Comment: Hmm, hard to give advice without the code.  Are you willing to post to github?

Answer (score 0):

In the identity inspector of the utilities panel take a close look at the Custom Class section where you linked your xib to the swift file.  Make sure the Module field has your current module selected.n I have seen this field blank and have not been able to create IBOutlets until it is set properly.